# Выполнить событие перед инициализацией UserControl'а c#\WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, события

Есть панель `public class MyPanel : UserControl;` Мне нужно инициировать событие перед инициализацией и после.
Пытался реализовать вот так, но ничего не работает... Вот код

```
public class MyPanel : UserControl
{
        string ID = "1";
        public MyPanel()
        {
            OnInitializeBegin();
            InitializeComponent();
            OnInitializeEnd();
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent InitializeBeginEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "InitializeBegin", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyPanel));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent InitializeEndEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "InitializeEnd", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyPanel));

        public event RoutedEventHandler InitializeBegin
        {
            add { AddHandler(InitializeBeginEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(InitializeBeginEvent, value); }
        }
        public event RoutedEventHandler InitializeEnd
        {
            add { AddHandler(InitializeEndEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(InitializeEndEvent, value); }
        }

        protected virtual void OnInitializeBegin()
        {
            if (InitializeBeginEvent != null)
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(InitializeBeginEvent, ID));
        }

        protected virtual void OnInitializeEnd()
        {
            if (InitializeEndEvent != null)
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(InitializeEndEvent, ID));
        }
}
```

И в XAML'е главного окна подписываюсь на ивенты:

```
<Grid>    
    <cp:MyPanel InitializeBegin="MyPanel_PanelInitializationBegin" InitializeEnd="MyPanel_PanelInitializationEnd"/>
</Grid>
```

Потом ставлю брейкпоинты на обработчики и они просто не срабатывают... Посмотрите пожалуйста в чем у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хороший вопрос!

То, как вы пишете, не сработает. Дело вот в чём. Посмотрите на XAML-код

```
<Grid>    
    <cp:MyPanel InitializeBegin="MyPanel_PanelInitializationBegin"
                InitializeEnd="MyPanel_PanelInitializationEnd"/>
</Grid>
```

Этот код примерно соответствует следующему C#-коду:

```
// создаём внешний элемент
Grid grid = new Grid();

// создаём внутренний элемент
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel(); // (*)
myPanel.InitializeBegin += this.MyPanel_PanelInitializationBegin;
myPanel.InitializeEnd += this.MyPanel_PanelInitializationEnd;

// подсоединяем их
grid.Children.Add(myPanel);
```

Ваши события запускаются как часть *конструктора* `MyPanel`, а значит, отрабатывают в пределах строки `(*)`. Но подписка происходит *после* отработки конструктора! Так что ваши события происходят тогда, когда их никто не ожидает.

Вообще, отправлять события в конструкторе в принципе плохая затея. Ведь до того, как конструктор отработал, ни у кого нету ссылок на ваш объект (если вы только не применяете некоторые грязные трюки), а значит, никто не может подписаться на его события. Так что проблема не в WPF или XAML'е, вы просто хотите невозможного. Даже если бы это как-то и было возможно, до окончания отработки конструктора объект находится в недоинициализированном состоянии, а значит, разрешать другим объектам видеть этот объект и работать с ним — неправильно, объект должен сначала полностью прийти в хорошее, полностью инициализированное состояние.

Судя по всему, вам придётся поменять архитектуру.

Comment: Ну моя затея, это подписатся на ивенты и собрать список контроллов которые инициировались, и время инициализации для каждого такого контрола, вот и все, как это сделать по другому я не знаю... Ну а то, что ивенты вызываются после инициализации я сам уже понял, по этому пришлось для каждого контрола писать мои статические методы, до и после `InitializeComponent()`, возможно это и не совсем рпавильно, но работает просто на отлично... Еще думал способ передачи обработчиков в статический конструктор контролов, но это слишком уже геморно, лучше руками забить, тем болие что контролов 15 штук всего..

Comment: Делайте не так. Пусть контрол сам измеряет своё время инициализации, и складывает результаты в глобальную таблицу.

Comment: Ну я так и сделал, просто контрол для "складывания в глобальную таблицу" использует глобальные статик методы, думаю такой вариант не хуже создания этих методов в базовом классе контрола... А измирения у меня проводит конеч но же сам контрол, в его конструкторе, я вот думал какбы так придумать что бы не писать код измирений для каждого контрола отдельно, как то бы сделать это в базовом классе или что...